# Pass arguments of 3D numpy array into a 4D numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to sort a 4D numpy array by the result of an numpy.argsort evaluated on a reduced 3D version of that array. Something like this:

```
array.shape
    (7, 3178, 3178, 3)
array_reduced.shape
    (7, 3178, 3178)
args=numpy.argsort(array_reduced,axis=0)
array_sorted=array[args,:]
```

This returns a memory error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-48-04f432d9e05d> in <module>()
          ----> 1 array_sorted=array[args,:]

    MemoryError:
```

This may be a stupid mistake about how to cast lambda functions, but if someone could help me I would really appreciate it!

-------------------------------------- EDIT -----------------------

This code does what I want it to do but it is v slow:

```
array_sorted=np.zeros(array.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
for thet in range (0, array.shape[0]):
    print(thet)
    for y in range (0, array.shape[1]):
        for x in range (0, array.shape[2]):
            array_sorted[thet,y,x,0]=(array[args[thet,y,x],y,x,0])
            array_sorted[thet,y,x,1]=(array[args[thet,y,x],y,x,1])
            array_sorted[thet,y,x,2]=(array[args[thet,y,x],y,x,2])
```

Comment: `MemoryError` just means that your computer doesn't have enough RAM to do the calculation. Assuming you are using arrays of floats64, each of your arrays is about 2Gb of data so with the typical amount of RAM in nowadays computer you can quickly fill it all up.

Comment: I'm using a large workstation - assuming I have enough RAM should the code work correctly? Also these arrays are uint8

Comment: It seems like it is not doing what you expect. `array[args,:]` is building an array of shape (7, 3178, 3178, 3178, 3178), I'm not sure what is going on exactly but I'll try to investigate ...

Comment: An array of shape (7, 3178, 3178, 3178, 3178) would certainly give a memory error! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize your loop using `np.ogrid`:

```
i,j,k = np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, array.shape[:-1]))]
array_sorted = array[args, j, k]
```